# Splitting a django app in two parts for security?

Tags: django, apache

I've got a django app that is basically two parts: first is the front facing website using templates and such, second is basically a lot of reporting data that I generate.

Both pieces operate on the same data, using the same database, etc.  However, I want to make the backend reporting to be as secure as possible.

What's the best way to secure the reporting piece?  Is it sufficient to just place decorators on the views and restrict via IP?

or would something like Apache level ip restriction be better?

I understand IP restriction works the same way in both cases, although somehow I feel if I have reports in a separate apache virtual host with allow/deny restrictions, it would seem securer than the Django way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I decided to just add a decorator to the view functions restricted by an ip.

Answer (score 0):

Maverick,

If you have control over the network your running on and could open up a non standard port to this application and then only allow connections from certain ip's on that port that would be the earliest you should be able to keep unwanted connections out.

Without doing that I would tend to think doing both would be best. Set up the second app to only allow connections from certain ip's with apache and then be sure to restrict access to the views. If you have links to the reporting section you could also control their display with something like the following. It is a template tag that checks if the user belongs to the required group.

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1576/

Comment: Well, why would you do it twice (at Apache level), and and with the views?  Wouldn't at Apache level suffice?